# Keeping Up To Date With All Things C#

Tags: c#

How do developers keep up to date with new C# features?

Are there famous / popular blogs that people subscribe to?

What else can developers do to keep at the forefront of changes

Comment: Jon Skeet's blog? http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/default.aspx

Comment: Two good ones, which happen to be by frequent SO contributors, are http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/ and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/Default.aspx

Comment: This should be a community wiki

Answer (score 4):

Actually there aren't so many new features in the language itself as you might think. Personally I am keeping track of [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/).

Answer (score 2):

Visit this site regularly, and be sure not to miss Jon Skeet's answers and comments..

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has a very nice preconfigured RSS feed on it's start window. It's updated regularly with posts from various MSDN blogs and usually contains very helpful information on .NET technology and programming examples (LINQ-kungfu, C# 4.0 features and so on). If nothing else I'd recommend to check it out once a day.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the .Net Rocks podcast.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the good answers already written, I would recommend Bill Wagner's books: [More effective C#: 50 specific ways to improve your C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890) which gives you a real insight into C# great possibilities. Ok it isn't online, it's just an old-fashioned book, but when you read, you forget that inconvenient. Besides, there are new editions to cover new versions. To my mind, this book, Jon Skeet's blog and msdn website can be great references for C# developers